# "Pinging" using DNS protocol

Tags: networking, dns, programming

Is there accepted "good practice" for checking that the network connection to a DNS server is operational, and that the server responds minimally, other than issuing a lookup request? Looking at the code for Nagios as a particular example I notice that it appears to be oriented towards "does this name resolve?" rather than "is the server OK?".

I've tried a null query but it appears to be ignored. I've tried requesting server status and while some respond (typically with "not implemented") others ignore the request. I'd prefer something better than relying on ping since I've seen plenty of server systems which ignore pings, and because of the extra hassle of messing around with capabilities etc.

At present I suspect that the only consistently reliable solution would be to lookup something like google.com, on the assumption that the server will have this cached to will expend minimal effort responding: since I need to do this every few minutes I don't want to upset its owner.

Comment: Is this for a monitoring solution? Running a DNS query every N minutes really shouldn't affect the server.

Comment: Yes. I'm updating some legacy code which was originally on Windows, and one of the things it does is check that it can see certain crucial network resources. On error it stops reporting success to a local tree of servers via UDP (i.e. "fails safe"), and starts making noises using MIDI. I find that newer application servers are being fed the address of external serves via DHCP, and I'm interested on minimising any chance that I might upset their owners.

Comment: A recursive or an authoritative nameserver?

Comment: Presumably recursive: whatever BT makes specifies to fibre users via DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 6303](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apd/rfc6303.txt) lists a number of DNS zones essentially every DNS server should be able to answer for, basically to stop those queries from being needlessly propagated towards the root of the DNS hierarchy, if those zones are not used for any local purpose.

The oldest and most well-known of those is the reverse zone for the loopback network, and in particular, the PTR record for IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 (i.e. the FQDN `1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.`). Basically, every DNS server *should* be able to provide that without querying any other DNS server.

So, although `dig -x 127.0.0.1 @dns-server-address` is technically a query for a particular record, it effectively is applicable as "is the server OK?" test, since that is a record *every* DNS server should be able to resolve with minimal effort and without contacting any other DNS server.

The query for the name `localhost.` should be practically just as good, just note that you should explicitly include the full stop at the end to indicate that the name you're querying is already fully qualified, to prevent the tool you're using from possibly adding your local domain suffix which might skew the results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate and report back.

Comment: Querying localhost at the remote server appears reliable, and hopefully it's such a stupiq question BT won't think I'm trying to hack them :-)

Comment: As long as you restrict yourself to reasonable polling intervals, your queries will probably be lost in the noise of an untold number of misconfigured computers, stupid software and embedded devices emitting queries for localhost. I expect they won't even notice :-)

Comment: The regime I'm using is that the servers in resolv.conf are "flattened" i.e. any priority etc. is ignored, and one selected at random is checked every 5 * random(24) i.e. every minute on average. Historically, it's been applied to internal servers and since at present DHCP is returning external addresses I might reduce the rate. I'd add that for the last 20 years or so I've been running Nagios against customers' mailservers etc., and only once has one queried it... which turned out to be because a bug in Nagios was sending a malformed SMTP message which was showing up in their logs :-)